# Moving From non-Java Ruby to Groovy: Language Differences

Tags: java, ruby, groovy

Using my not-outstanding Google skills, I have not been able to find a decent tutorial on Groovy for Ruby programmers. There are a lot of political pieces (Ruby is great! Groovy is great!) and tiny little contrasts, but I really don't care which is better. I know Ruby (and Java) relatively well, and I'd like to learn Groovy.

Would anybody care to (either provide an amazing link or) mark some differences between the two languages in terms of how to do things (syntactic, class declaration, loops, blocks, etc.)? For my purposes you can assume full Java competence to explain.

Again, I am not interested in knowing which is better. Just need to know how to do stuff....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see [this](http://blog.headius.com/2008/04/converting-groovy-to-ruby.html) and [this](http://www.glenstampoultzis.net/blog/?p=61)?
Relatively short posts, I know.  You're right; there doesn't appear to be much...

update: [two](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/16-introduction-to-groovy-scripting-language-1.html) more [links](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java).

Answer (score 5):

If you know Java, the best thing you can read is how the metaClass is used in Groovy. Here's a decent explanation: http://skillsmatter.com/downloads/Groovy%20User%20Group%20December%202006.pdf

Just remember that everything in Groovy runs through the metaClass. The seemingly simple statements:

```
a = foo.bar
bar = b
foo.baz(1,2,3)
```

Translate roughly into this Java:

```
a = foo.getMetaClass().getProperty("bar");
this.getMetaClass().setProperty("bar",b);
foo.getMetaClass().invokeMethod("baz",new Object[] {1,2,3});
```

Everything is dispatched through the metaClass, which is how pretty much all the Groovy "language" features work. The most important feature is probably [closures](http://groovy.dzone.com/news/higher-order-functions-groovy--1). What you need to remember about closures is that it's all metaClass trickery. The closure's metaClass can be setup to try invoking methods/resolve properties on its delegate, which basically means you can do things like invoke a method on an object that doesn't have that method.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but helpful so +1 :)

Comment: Ditto, not answering question but non the less really helpful for anybody getting into groovy... like me;-) So +1

Answer (score 2):

We need more questions like this one.  Three years after the question, there's still a comparitive lack of information on this moving betwen these two similar languages.

I did find this Slide Share presentation, which covers a lot of basic ground.

- **[Comparing groovy and (j)ruby](http://fr.slideshare.net/dnosenko/comparing-groovy-andjrubynealford)**

And this blog post was helpful with 'simple' stuff because it give a bit more background:

- **[Thoughts on Groovy](http://smellsblue.blogspot.com.au/2008/06/thoughts-on-groovy.html)**

The reasons to switch between languages usually have more to do with project needs than a language itself and I feel its important able to swap and compare between tools.

One standard resource for this kind of question is: **[Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Groovy)**.

Hope to see some more tips added to this list.

Cheers,
       Will

Answer (score 1):

The differences between Java and Groovy are less than the differences between Ruby and Groovy, so if you know both Ruby and Java, it probably makes more sense to look for a "Groovy for Java programmers" book or tutorial.

IMO, the best Groovy book on the market is [Programming Groovy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356093). It's the most up-to-date book that I know of (though still a few versions behind the latest release), is pretty concise, and covers some relatively advanced topics in quite a bit of detail (e.g. meta object protocol).

Comment: Thanks Don, I'm going through an excellent book on Groovy right now, but there's more to life than learning. There's also remembering. I need a list of differences between Ruby and Groovy to keep them straight now and later. At some point I'll make the list, though, and put a link to it in this question.

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, what's the "excellent book on Groovy"?

Comment: Hi @don sorry I never saw this because it wasn't addressed, and now I have no idea ;) Hope all is well!

Answer (score 0):

The Groovy wiki has a good article entitled [Groovy style and language feature guidelines for Java developers](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+style+and+language+feature+guidelines+for+Java+developers).

Comment: That's not too relevant to this question.

Comment: I'm not sure how this isn't relevant to your question. The article discusses groovy syntax and assumes you are familiar with Java - for example comparing property setting between Java and Groovy.

Comment: Also, learning about idiomatic Groovy programming style is going to be important if you want to read existing Groovy source code and understand it thoroughly.